# objective-c gettimeofday function alternatives

Tags: objective-c, gettimeofday

I'm using gettimeofday in my program for time intervals like that:

```
struct timeval currentTime, startTime; 
gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
startTime.tv_usec /= 1000;
gettimeofday(&currentTime, NULL);
currentTime.tv_usec /= 1000;

long int msSinceStart = (currentTime.tv_usec + (1000 * currentTime.tv_sec) ) - (startTime.tv_usec + (1000 * startTime.tv_sec) );
```

Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: `gettimeofday` deprecated with Xcode 5.1 ?? where this came from ?

Comment: it shows a warning "implicit declaration of function 'gettimeofday' is invalid in c99"

Comment: Implicit declaration of a function, doesn't mean deprecated… Just include <sys/time.h> and the error vanished.

Comment: @user2282782 your question should be demanding solution, if there is no option then should go for alternative, emmanuel is right

Answer (score 3):

@user2282782 Noted in their comments that the real issue behind the question was that the warning `gettimeofday is invalid in c99` is being thrown in at compile time.

To resolve the issue, as @Emmanuel pointed out, just add: 
`#include <sys/time.h>` to the top of the file. That solved my same problem with this as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543542-cfabsolutetimegetcurrent):

```
CFAbsoluteTime start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

and to get the number of seconds that have elapsed:

```
CFTimeInterval elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start;
```

---

Note, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1543542-cfabsolutetimegetcurrent) for `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` warns us:

> Repeated calls to this function do not guarantee monotonically increasing results. The system time may decrease due to synchronization with external time references or due to an explicit user change of the clock.

This means that if you're unfortunate enough to measure elapsed time when one of these adjustments take place, you can end up with incorrect elapsed time calculation. This caveat also applies to `NSDate` and similar functions. To get around this, you can use [`CACurrentMediaTime`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1395996-cacurrentmediatime):

```
CFTimeInterval start = CACurrentMediaTime();
```

and

```
CFTimeInterval elapsed = CACurrentMediaTime() - start;
```

This uses `mach_absolute_time`, but avoids some of its complexities outlined in [Technical Q&A QA1398](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Objective-C alternative is NSDate.

```
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval secondsSinceStart = -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

Of course, if you want a hi-res time, you should be using mach_absolute_time (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Now to resolve this issue you should insert to your file this:

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`